# Normal vector field for an immersion

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles, vector-fields, orientation

I know that a hypersurface $M$ of a riemannian manifold $N$ is orientable iff there exists a globally defined unit normal vector field $\eta : M \to TM^{\perp} \subset TN|_M$.

Does the same hold for a general immersion $f : M^n \to N^{n+1}$? That is,

> $M$ is orientable $\iff$ $\exists \, \eta : M \to TN$ with $\eta(p) \perp Df(p)(T_p M)$ and $\|\eta(p)\|=1$, $\, \forall p \in M$?

Comment: This is correct. The proof is the same.

Comment: Just work locally, where $f$ is an embedding?

Comment: This isn't a local theorem, so that won't work. Did your original proof really depend on the assumption that $M$ is a submanifold?